# Replace string only once with php preg_replace

Tags: regex, string, php

I need a replace string once function and believe preg_match might be my best bet.

I was using this, but due to the dynamicness of use, sometimes this function behaves strangely:

```
function str_replace_once($remove , $replace , $string)
{
    $pos = strpos($string, $remove);
    if ($pos === false) 
    {
    // Nothing found
    return $string;
    }
    return substr_replace($string, $replace, $pos, strlen($remove));
}
```

Now I am taking this approach but have ran to to the error listed below.... I'm parsing all kinds of html strings with this function, so its hard to give a value thats causing the error. As of now 80% of my uses of the below show this error .

```
function str_replace_once($remove , $replace , $string)
{
    $remove = str_replace('/','\/',$remove);
    $return = preg_replace("/$remove/", $replace, $string, 1);  
    return $return;
}
```

error:

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

Can anyone refine a solution?

Comment: you've included a limit on the replacements of 1 - do you really just want to replace the first instance of the pattern match? Anyway, I think including this when there is no match may be causing your problem with some replacement patterns.

Comment: See [
PHP: str_replace that only acts on the first match?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `preg_quote` instead of trying to escape the `\` yourself (which doesn't take `[`, `+` and many others into account):

```
$return = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($remove,'/').'/', $replace, $string, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com/docs/replace):

```
pattern('[a-z]+')->replace($string)->first()->with($replace);
```

and also you should not use `preg_quote()`, as it's not safe - try [Prepared Patterns](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input).