# Using preg_replace to replace only first match

Tags: php, regex, string

I am testing the str_replace in phpList and I want to replace the first match of a string. I found on other posts that I should use preg_replace if I want to replace the first match of a string, the problem is preg_replace does not return a string for some reason.

Both

```
$fp = fopen('/var/www/data.txt', 'w');
$string_test = preg_replace(basename($html_images[$i]), "cid:$cid", $this->Body,1);
fwrite($fp,$string_test);
fclose($fp);
```

and

```
$fp = fopen('/var/www/data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp,preg_replace(basename($html_images[$i]), "cid:$cid", $this->Body,1));
fclose($fp);
```

writes an empty string to the file. I would like to know how to get a return string and str_replace does not seem to work with first match. However, str_replace would return a string.

Comment: preg_replace accepts a regular expression as first parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace string only once with php preg\_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392508/replace-string-only-once-with-php-preg-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace)'s does a Regular Expression match and replace. You are passing it a string instead of a valid RegEx as the first argument.

Instead you might be looking for [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) which does string replacement.

Comment: I will look into Regular Expression. I tried this fwrite($fp,str_replace(basename($html_images[$i]), "cid:$cid", $this->Body,1)); with str_replace, it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `preg_replace()` is the wrong tool if you just want to perform a regular find & replace operation. You could perform a single replacement using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/str_pos) and [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/substr_replace) for instance:

```
$find = basename($html_images[$i]);
$string_test = $this->Body;
if (($pos = strpos($string_test, $find)) !== false) {
    $string_test = substr_replace($string_test, "cid:$cid", $pos, strlen($find));
}
```

With `preg_replace()` you would get something like this:

```
$string_test = preg_replace('~' . preg_quote(basename($html_images[$i], '~') . '~', "cid:$cid", $this->Body, 1);
```

For convenience, you can wrap either two into a function called `str_replace_first()`.