# Case Insensitive replace php for First Present

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: str_replace that only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Now I used `str_ireplace($find,$replace,$str)` which replaces all the words which are present in `$str`. 
I want to replace first occurrence of a word in a string with the given string.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Comment: Just a thought, the difference being this question is looking for case insensitive, look at the i flag for preg_match and use the answer linked to by Jonny.