# Replace all the _ except one before last one

Tags: php, regex

I have the following url:

```
http://distilleryimage3_s3_amazonaws_com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7_jpg
```

I want to replace the `_` with `.`. However, the `_7` at the end should be kept - it is not a dot.

So, basically it should look like:

```
http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7.jpg
```

If I use str_replace it will replace all the `_` but I need to keep that one there. How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you getting this input from?

Comment: Why don't you replace up to the first single '/' slash. Anything following the slash keep. Once complete, start from the end and replace the single _ with a .

Comment: Check out the solution to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510223/php-str-replace-with-a-limit-param - You could use `substr_count` to get the total occurrences and subtract 1 to get your limit

Comment: How did the URL get mangled? How about you, like, not replace the dots with underscores in the first place.

Comment: Is this only going to be used once?  If not, how can you be sure the exact same underscore will need to be kept every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this (**corrected now!**)

```
<?php
$subject = 'http://distilleryimage3_s3_amazonaws_com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7_jpg';
$pattern = '/(_)(?!\d_jpg)/';


var_dump(preg_replace($pattern, '.', $subject));
```

This outputs

```
http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7.jpg
```

Comment: How about... if it is a random number rather than 7 placed at the end?

Comment: this would only fix this SPECIFIC string. OP wants a generalized solution for all possible AWS urls.

Comment: @TiagoSouEu It should work now (but it would fail in some cases, of course).

Comment: @TiagoSouEu I made another update, the pattern replaces all underscores except underscores followed by a digit, another underscore and 'jpg'. Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: There isn't group `\2` captured by your regex.

Comment: @TiagoSouEu - Just because it works now, doesn't mean it will work in a future variation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't use regex (works for all numbers, so this won't fail if the number is different from `7`; it doesn't have to be a number -- a string works, too):

```
 <?php

$haystack = 'http://distilleryimage3_s3_amazonaws_com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7_jpg';

//replacing all '_' with '.'
$haystack = str_replace('_', '.', $haystack);

//finding second last occurence of '.'
$n = strrpos($haystack, '.', strrpos($haystack, '.') - strlen($haystack) - 1);

//replacing the nth character to '_'
$haystack[$n] = '_';

echo $haystack;
```

Output:

```
http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7.jpg
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/IJqr0nEE)

Comment: What if there are other dots `.` in the url, at the end?

Comment: @randunel: The domain extension doesn't matter. And I don't see how it's possible to have multiple dots for image URLs.

Comment: haven't you ever seen a file named `my.super.cat.jpg`? It's possible. And I can serve anything through any url, including `example.com/my.super.dotted.endpoint`

Comment: @randunel: Yeah, it'd fail in that case, but the OP hasn't mentioned about it, so I just went with a general solution, that'd work for *most* of the URLs. It's always possible to find exceptions ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this **negative lookahead** based regex code:

```
$s='http://distilleryimage3_s3_amazonaws_com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7_jpg';
$repl = preg_replace('/_(?![^_]*_[^_]*$)/', '.', $s);
//=> http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/8af11cdcf11e286b022000ae90285_7.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The final _ in a string that is not itself.

```
 _(?=[^_]+$)
```

Edit: my assumption is that this question needs specific knowledge of file extensions to answered correctly.