# How to replace PHP only first and second word and not replace third word?

Tags: php, replace

How to replace PHP only first and second word and not replace third word ?

I have

```
$test = "hello i love animal love dog and and love tree";
```

I want to replace fisrt and secode word `love` to `underscore` and not replace third word `love` like this.

```
hello i _ animal _ dog and and love tree
```

Then i use this code

```
$test = str_replace('love', '_', $test);
echo $test;
```

But result will be

```
hello i _ animal _ dog and and _ tree
```

How can i do for replace only first and second word and not replace third word ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP str\_replace() with a limit param?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510223/php-str-replace-with-a-limit-param)

Comment: @Rulisp no limit param on str_replace(), there is a count param, but that allows you to pass a variable in as a pointer in order to get the number of instances of the string that were replaced. It doesn't actually allow you to limit the number of instances to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the result you are looking for:

```
$subject = "hello i love animal love dog and and love tree";
$search = "love";
$replace = "_";

$pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

$first_subject = str_replace($search, $replace, substr($subject, 0, $pos));
$subject = $first_subject . substr($subject, $pos, strlen($subject));

echo $subject;
```

Demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05b9bcaaefb207e3629dcdb168775f281c574fda)

Comment: Oh best ans ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex-free way:

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba82cacca8d49a5b9aee0033cfed7d7d04e1f7d0)):

```
$test = "hello i love animal love dog and and love tree";
$test=substr_replace($test,"_",strpos($test,"love"),4);
$test=substr_replace($test,"_",strpos($test,"love"),4);
echo $test;
```

Output:

```
hello i _ animal _ dog and and love tree
```

This method is simple because it does the same method twice -- each time it removes "love at first sight".

Comment: not work , i want output `hello i _ animal _ dog and and love tree` how can i do ?

Comment: @mongkontiya Sorry my mistake, I have fixed my method.  I think it is actually simpler than my first method.