# replace only the first instance of a substring

Tags: php

```
$patha = 'BIN/BIN/test.php';
$count = 1;
$pathb = str_replace('BIN', 'SYSTEM', $patha, $count);
echo $pathb;
```

Result:

```
SYSTEM/SYSTEM/test.php
```

I want to replace only the first instance of `BIN`, so result should be:

`SYSTEM/BIN/test.php`

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP str\_replace() with a limit param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510223/php-str-replace-with-a-limit-param)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with `$limit` param

```
preg_replace('/BIN/', 'SYSTEM', $patha, 1);
```

Because str_replace `$count` param is not limit as you waiting for

Answer (score 1):

From the manual: [PHP: str_replace - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), it clearly says the syntax here:

> `mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )`

And then for the `$count`:

> `count`
>   If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

It's not the number of replacements, the function is going to take. Your `$count` value gets updated telling that you have got 2 replacements made. To limit the number of replacements made, please use `preg_replace`. Or another function given in the manual:

> ```
> <?php
>     /**
>      * Replace $limit occurences of the search string with the replacement
>      * @param mixed $search The value being searched for. An array may be used to
>      * designate multiple needles.
>      * @param mixed $replace The replacement value that replaces found search
>      * values. An array may be used to designate multiple replacements.
>      * @param mixed $subject The string or array being searched and replaced on. If
>      * subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with every
>      * entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well. 
>      * @param string $count If passed, this will be set to the number of
>      * replacements performed.
>      * @param int $limit The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each
>      * subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).
>      * @return string This function returns a string with the replaced values.
>      */
>     function str_replace_limit($search, $replace, $subject, &$count, $limit = -1)
>     {
>         $count = 0;
>         // Invalid $limit provided
>         if (!($limit === strval(intval(strval($limit))))) {
>             trigger_error('Invalid $limit `' . $limit . '` provided. Expecting an ' . 'integer', E_USER_WARNING);
>             return $subject;
>         }
>         // Invalid $limit provided
>         if ($limit < -1) {
>             trigger_error('Invalid $limit `' . $limit . '` provided. Expecting -1 or ' . 'a positive integer', E_USER_WARNING);
>             return $subject;
>         }
>         // No replacements necessary
>         if ($limit === 0) {
>             trigger_error('Invalid $limit `' . $limit . '` provided. Expecting -1 or ' . 'a positive integer', E_USER_NOTICE);
>             return $subject;
>         }
>         // Use str_replace() when possible
>         if ($limit === -1) {
>             return str_replace($search, $replace, $subject, $count);
>         }
>         if (is_array($subject)) {
>             // Loop through $subject values
>             foreach ($subject as $key => $this_subject) {
>                 // Skip values that are arrays
>                 if (!is_array($this_subject)) {
>                     // Call this function again
>                     $this_function = __FUNCTION__;
>                     $subject[$key] = $this_function($search, $replace, $this_subject, $this_count, $limit);
>                     // Adjust $count
>                     $count += $this_count;
>                     // Adjust $limit
>                     if ($limit != -1) {
>                         $limit -= $this_count;
>                     }
>                     // Reached $limit
>                     if ($limit === 0) {
>                         return $subject;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             return $subject;
>         } elseif (is_array($search)) {
>             // Clear keys of $search
>             $search = array_values($search);
>             // Clear keys of $replace
>             if (is_array($replace)) {
>                 $replace = array_values($replace);
>             }
>             // Loop through $search
>             foreach ($search as $key => $this_search) {
>                 // Don't support multi-dimensional arrays
>                 $this_search = strval($this_search);
>                 // If $replace is an array, use $replace[$key] if exists, else ''
>                 if (is_array($replace)) {
>                     if (array_key_exists($key, $replace)) {
>                         $this_replace = strval($replace[$key]);
>                     } else {
>                         $this_replace = '';
>                     }
>                 } else {
>                     $this_replace = strval($replace);
>                 }
>                 // Call this function again for
>                 $this_function = __FUNCTION__;
>                 $subject       = $this_function($this_search, $this_replace, $subject, $this_count, $limit);
>                 // Adjust $count
>                 $count += $this_count;
>                 // Adjust $limit
>                 if ($limit != -1) {
>                     $limit -= $this_count;
>                 }
>                 // Reached $limit
>                 if ($limit === 0) {
>                     return $subject;
>                 }
>             }
>             return $subject;
>         } else {
>             $search  = strval($search);
>             $replace = strval($replace);
>             // Get position of first $search
>             $pos     = strpos($subject, $search);
>             // Return $subject if $search cannot be found
>             if ($pos === false) {
>                 return $subject;
>             }
>             // Get length of $search
>             $search_len = strlen($search);
>             // Loop until $search cannot be found or $limit is reached
>             for ($i = 0; (($i < $limit) || ($limit === -1)); $i++) {
>                 $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, $search_len);
>                 // Increase $count
>                 $count++;
>                 // Get location of next $search
>                 $pos = strpos($subject, $search);
>                 // Break out of loop
>                 if ($pos === false) {
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>             return $subject;
>         }
>     }
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

How about that with only replace first occurrence of matched string?

```
<?php
/**
 * replace only the first occurrence of str matched
 */
function str_replace_first_only($from, $to, $content,$count)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, $count); // remove only first occurrence
}

$patha = 'BIN/BIN/test.php';
$count = 1;
$pathb = str_replace_first_only('BIN', 'SYSTEM', $patha, $count);
echo $pathb;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
SYSTEM/BIN/test.php
```

**Working DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/OaVcP