# PHP randomly replace words

Tags: php, string, random, replace

I have an array called $featuresSEO that has a number of words in it like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Japan 
    [1] => Japanese 
    [2] => Tokyo 
    [3] => Yokohama 
    [4] => Osaka 
    [5] => Asian 
    [6] => Nagoya 
)
```

I then have a string like follows:

```
 Searching the |*-*| Dating membership database is the key to locating |*-*| people
 you would be interested in. You can search for |*-*| Singles including |*-*| Women
 and |*-*| Men in any location worldwide. Join now to search for |*-*| Singles.
```

I've been trying to replace the instances of `|*-*|` with random words from the Array. I've tried str_replace() but couldn't get the random aspect working.

Can someone push me in the right direction?

thx

Comment: Is every `|*-*|` random, or is one random word chosen and then used for all `|*-*|`?

Comment: each one a random word... so different words through the string

Comment: Use the random() function to get a random index, and then replace `|*-*|` by your `Array[your_random_index]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for replace-only-first-match is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match). The following code uses each word from the list only once:

```
$wordlist = array(
    'Japan',
    'Japanese',
    'Tokyo',
    'Yokohama',
    'Osaka',
    'Asian',
    'Nagoya'
);
$string = "
Searching the |*-*| Dating membership database is the key to locating |*-*| people
you would be interested in. You can search for |*-*| Singles including |*-*| Women
and |*-*| Men in any location worldwide. Join now to search for |*-*| Singles.
";
$replace = '|*-*|';
while(true){
    $index = strpos($string, $replace);
    if($index === false){
        // ran out of place holder strings
        break;
    }
    if(count($wordlist) == 0){
        // ran out of words
        break;
    }
    $word = array_splice($wordlist, rand(0, count($wordlist) - 1), 1);
    $string = substr_replace($string, $word[0], $index, strlen($replace));
}
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace them one by one. This one will replace each occurence with a random word. You might see the same word from the `$wordarray` multiple times as it picks 1 at random each time.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < substr_count($string, '|*-*|'); $i++){
     $string = preg_replace('/\|\*-\*\|/',$wordarray[rand(0,count($wordarray)-1)],$string, 1);
}
```

Want to use each word only once? Shuffle the array, and loop through it:

```
shuffle($wordarray);
foreach ($wordarray as $word){
    $string = preg_replace('/\|\*-\*\|/',$word,$string,1);
}
```

Comment: Will replace all items with the first randomly chosen item, wont it?

Comment: nope. I've put a `1` as 4th parameter. So it will only replace 1 occurence

Comment: 4th parameter gives me a warning!

Comment: @Topener the last argument needs to be a reference

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$string = ' Searching the |*-*| Dating membership database is the key to locating |*-*| people
 you would be interested in. You can search for |*-*| Singles including |*-*| Women
 and |*-*| Men in any location worldwide. Join now to search for |*-*| Singles.';

$words = array('Japanese', 'Tokyo', 'Asian');

$placeholder = '|*-*|';
$pos = null;

while(null === $pos || false !== $pos) {
    $pos = strpos($string, $placeholder);
    $string = substr_replace($string, $words[rand(0, count($words)-1)], $pos, strlen($placeholder));

}

echo $string;
```

first word become unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $array = array("Japan","Japanese","Tokyo","Yokohama","Osaka","Asian","Nagoya");
    $a = array_rand($array);
    $string= "abc|*-*|";
    echo str_replace("|*-*|", $array[$a], $string);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP already has a native function which allows you to replace placeholders in a template string with an array of strings -- `vprintf()` *variable print from format* if I am not mistaken.

If you had originally set up your template with recognised placeholders, you wouldn't need to call `str_replace()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/u0rsW))

```
$template = 'Searching the |*-*| Dating membership database is the key to locating |*-*| people
 you would be interested in. You can search for |*-*| Singles including |*-*| Women
 and |*-*| Men in any location worldwide. Join now to search for |*-*| Singles.';

$array = ['Japan', 'Japanese', 'Tokyo', 'Yokohama', 'Osaka', 'Asian', 'Nagoya'];

shuffle($array);
vprintf(str_replace('|*-*|', '%s', $template), $array);
```

Potential output:

```
Searching the Asian Dating membership database is the key to locating Japan people
 you would be interested in. You can search for Osaka Singles including Nagoya Women
 and Yokohama Men in any location worldwide. Join now to search for Tokyo Singles.
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is still relevant)

```
$wordarray = [
   'some',
   'random',
   'words',
   'list'
];
shuffle($wordarray);
$string = implode(' ', $wordarray);
```

You can change implode to sprintf, that was my realization.

Comment: The OP wants random words to be filled into a pattern. In this case, it will replace the character array |*-*|