# php replace first occurrence of string from 0th position

Tags: php, string, replace, substring

I want to search and replace the first word with another in php like as follows:

```
$str="nothing inside";
```

Replace 'nothing' to 'something' by search and replace without using `substr`

output should be: 'something inside'

Comment: Regular expressions are much more expensive performance wise than working with other methods. **Never default to regex unless you have given serious consideration to other programming approaches to your problem!** With currently 36K views already how much human time has been wasted around the world via by bad performance programed by amateurs who did *not* have a better / correct approach to their related problems?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a limit of 1:

```
preg_replace('/nothing/', 'something', $str, 1);
```

Replace the regular expression `/nothing/` with whatever string you want to search for. Since regular expressions are always evaluated left-to-right, this will always match the first instance.

Comment: This solution has escaping issues if you're just using generic strings, such as if $ and such are within the string.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match has a more generic solution.

Comment: **Regular expressions should *never* be treated as the first go-to option in any programming language** due to their higher resource usage *period*. For the less experienced: if you have not spent serious time trying to determine another approach to the problem then it's far from the appropriate time to even consider regex.

Answer (score 14):

on the man page for str_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) you can find this function

```
function str_replace_once($str_pattern, $str_replacement, $string){

    if (strpos($string, $str_pattern) !== false){
        $occurrence = strpos($string, $str_pattern);
        return substr_replace($string, $str_replacement, strpos($string, $str_pattern), strlen($str_pattern));
    }

    return $string;
}
```

usage sample: http://codepad.org/JqUspMPx

Comment: same as preg_replace('/search/','replace',$str,1);

Comment: @Ben The functions are the similar, but definitely not the same. If you use a character that needs to be escaped by a regular expression, you will get unexpected errors if you use preg_replace.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z]\s/', 'ReplacementWord ', $string)
```

what it does is select anything from start till first white space and replace it with replcementWord . notice a space after replcementWord. this is because we added `\s` in search string

Comment: Me too, not so good at regEx. You can try this link [So You Want to Learn Regular Expressions?] (http://www.stedee.id.au/Learn_Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Sorry, but i cant format it properly

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect -- I don't understand why it has received 3 upvotes.  It is clearly an untested post.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/nothing/', 'something', $str, 1);
```

Comment: This will replace all occurrence. preg_replace('/OR/',' ',$str,1) replaces first occurrence of 'OR' but not only the leading occurrence

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow.  Please explain how your answer works and why it is a good idea.  Those who are not familiar with `preg_replace()` may not know why you chose this function nor what the parameters are doing.  Please do some something/anything to improve the educational value of this post.

Answer (score -1):

I ran to this issue and wanted a solution and this wasn't 100% right for me because if the string was like `$str = "mine'this` , the appostrophe would cause a problem. so I came up with a litle trick :

```
$stick='';
$cook = explode($str,$cookie,2);
        foreach($cook as $c){
            if(preg_match("/^'/", $c)||preg_match('/^"/', $c)){
                //we have 's dsf fds... so we need to find the first |sess| because it is the delimiter'
                $stick = '|sess|'.explode('|sess|',$c,2)[1];
            }else{
                $stick = $c;
            }
            $cookies.=$stick;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This checks and caches the first substring position in one command, next replacing it if present, should be the more compact and performant:

```
if(($offset=strpos($string,$replaced))!==false){
   $string=substr_replace($replaced,$replacer,$offset,strlen($replaced));
}
```

Comment: yes but these are an if and 2 function calls, nested, it should be auto explicative if you can understand the question, otherway you are not interested in the answer. AND I used very auto-explicative name variables, usually this should be enough to explain when the purpose of the code is known and the code lines are few

Answer (score -3):

[This function `str_replace`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is the one you are looking for.

Comment: that 4th parameter counts the replaces performed, doesn't limit the replacements to a number

Comment: You are right. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @steveoh: str_replace replaces all occurrence, but i want only the first occurrence if it exists in the start like ltrim function remove the first space only.

Comment: Obviously you should stick to the answer of *mganjoo*, would accept it as the answer.

Answer (score -4):

ltrim() will remove the unwanted text at the beginning of a string.

```
$do = 'nothing'; // what you want
$dont = 'something'; // what you dont want
$str = 'something inside';
$newstr = $do.ltrim( $str , $dont);
echo $newstr.'<br>';
```

Comment: ltrim() removes all characters in the given list, not the sequence of characters. Please update your answer.