# Replace one needle occurrence anywhere in the string without limits to first or last

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string, lets assume the string looks like "000110010111000011".

I would want to replace any occurrence of the number 1 in the string without limiting it to the first or last occurrence. I also want the string to return back the way it was, if needing to split it or something.

Comment: Have you looked into php's [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?..

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) PHP function. Here's how you can change all occurences of '1' in the string with '2':

```
$newString = str_replace('1', '2', '000110010111000011');
```

The `$newString` variable will contain the modified string

Comment: I don't think you understand. I want to replace only one occurrence not limiting it to the first or last. It can be first or last, I just don't want to limit it to either or.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598665/php-replace-first-occurence-of-string-from-0th-position - in particular, the str_replace_once() function defined there

Comment: I don't want to limit it to the first occurrence.