# how to extract part of string between first (variable) html-tag?

Tags: php, regex

I have some strings:

```
$string1 = '<p><strong>Extract me</strong></p><p>Leave me</p>';
$string2 = '<strong>Extract me</strong>Leave me';
$string3 = '<span style="font-weight: bold">Extract me</span><br /><span>Leave me</span>';
```

Let's check **$string3**:

The first tag of the string is **`<span>`**
So the text between the first `<span>` and the first `</span>` wants to be extracted.

Extracted shall mean: remove it from *$stringX* and save it into *$extractedX*

How would I do this?

Comment: I tried many things with regex but failed.
And I say shame on the guy who wrote the wikipedia-article.

Comment: In general I'd advice against using regex to parse html/xml structures. There are better ways (e.g. [Dom*](http://php.net/manual/book.dom.php), [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/book.simplexml.php)).

Comment: Sounds plausible.
But I have no idea how to solve my problem in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^>]*?(?=<\/.*>)
```

What you should do is use an assertion.  `[^>]*?` searches for any character that is NOT a `>`.  This should be fine since if you need to use `>` as text, it would need to be escaped as `&gt;`.  Then it searches for the first closing tag as denoted by `<\/.*>`.  The `(?=)` around it tells the regex engine not to include it in the match.

http://regexr.com?30pkm

Answer (score 1):

you have to be search first and then post your question here..
any ways here is the related question for your ans
[Click here to get the releted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

You can done it with [preg replace](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and regular expressions.

This online editor is useful for regex:

http://regexr.com?30pkp:

You'll need something like this to get started:

`<strong>(.*)</strong>|<span.+font-weight:\ ?bold.+>(.*)</span>`

If you need to do more advanced parsing you could look at parsing the DOM in PHP e.g. using [DOMDocument LoadHtml](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strip_tags](http://ca.php.net/strip_tags) with some use of [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) if you only want the first occurrence.