# How to change a word on string in php

Tags: php, string

How can i change a word on long string(text) in PHP?

Example:
Text: stackoverflow site is best site.

1) I want to change first "site" string to "website" but i don't want to change second "site".

2) how can i change second "site" without change first "site"?

3) how can i change all "site"?

Thanks

Comment: for your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Comment: @TNC: He wants to do it using PHP...

Comment: I worked hard on my answer just to see this question get downvoted. Perhaps with could help OP by editing the question instead?

Answer (score 2):

### All occurences

Easiest is to replace all occurrences. Just use [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) on your string

```
$str = 'stackoverflow site is best site';
$str = str_replace('site', 'website', $str);
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xq41W7)

### First occurence

To replace single instances (like the first, or second, or etc), you can use [`substr_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) which allows you to replace a certain character range with text. You have to find that range first though. You can use [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for that.

```
$str = 'stackoverflow site is best site';
$search = 'site';
$start = strpos($str, $search);
$str = substr_replace($str, 'website', $start, strlen($search));
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8Lfk9W)

### Any specific occurence

Now extending on the previous code to replace the second or third instances, you need to subsequently call [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and feed it the offset of the previous result. Here is a simple way to do it with a `for` loop.

```
$str = 'stackoverflow site is best site';
$search = 'site';
$count = 2;
$start = strpos($str, $search);
for($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++)
    $start = strpos($str, $search, $start + 1);
$str = substr_replace($str, 'website', $start, strlen($search));
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eAZTUi)

I am using a `$count` variable to determine what word I want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

1) Here's how you change first "site":

```
<?php
$string="stackoverflow site is best site.";
echo "<strong>First:</strong> ".$string;

$string_replace=preg_replace('/site/', 'website', $string, 1);
echo "<br /><strong>After:</strong> ".$string_replace;
?>
```

2) Here's how you change the last "site":

```
<?php
$string="stackoverflow site is best site.";
echo "<strong>First:</strong> ".$string;

$pos=strrpos($string, 'site');
$string_replace=substr_replace($string, 'website', $pos, strlen('site'));
echo "<br /><strong>After:</strong> ".$string_replace;
?>
```

3) Here's how you change all "site":

```
<?php
$string="stackoverflow site is best site.";
echo "<strong>First:</strong> ".$string;

$string_replace=str_replace("site", "website", $string);
echo "<br /><strong>After:</strong> ".$string_replace;
?>
```

That will change all "site" to "website".

Comment: You're not saving the return value from `str_replace`, so it's doing nothing. Also, the `count` parameter on `str_replace` is for **how many** replacements were made, not to specify a limit.

Comment: Your first `str_replace` won't replace the first "site".