# Replace the string for each occurrence in php?

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I would like to do some simple replacement using php.

For the first occurrence of "xampp" , replace it as "xp".

For the second / last occurrence of "xampp", replace it as "rrrr"

```
    $test = "http://localhost/xampp/splash/xampp/.php";

echo $test."<br>";
$count = 0;
$test = str_replace ("xampp","xp",$test,$count);

echo $test."<br>";

$count = 1;
$test = str_replace ("xampp","rrrr",$test,$count);
echo $test;
```

After looking the doc, I found that $count is to return the place where the string matchs only. It do not replace the string by specific occurrence assigned. So are there any ways to do the task?

Comment: preg_replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Comment: thanks for helping me, I don't realize has this function sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with `preg_replace_callback`, but `strpos` should be more efficient if the replacements aren't necessarily sequential.

```
function replaceOccurrence($subject, $find, $replace, $index) {
    $index = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i <= $index; $i++) {
        $index = strpos($subject, $find, $index);

        if($index === false) {
            return $subject;
        }
    }

    return substr($subject, 0, $index) . $replace . substr($subject, $index + strlen($find));
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ur6fUu)