# Code Igniter auto_link() messing my email addresses

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using auto_link() to output the copy from a CMS controlled page onto the front end. I have 2 email addresses, recruit@ and bankrecruit@ in the stored copy.

When I look at the front end the first email, recruit@, is auto_linked to become a linked email address but the second one becomes bank followed by the recruit@ email link. This is obviously not what I expected.

auto_link() is matching all cases of recruit@ in which case the bankrecruit@ is being converted as it finds recruit@ first and converts that.

If I remove the recruit@ then bankrecruit@ works fine. Also if I change the name to bank@ then both addresses work as expected.

Is there a resolution for this?

```
<p>This is the address a@test.com</p>
<p>This is the second address ba@test.com</p>
```

And the script is:

```
auto_link($content)
```

Comment: echo auto_link($page_content->page_body);

Comment: And this is the content: <p>This is the address a@test.com</p>
<p>This is the second address ba@test.com</p>

Comment: In that content a@test.com is converted to email links twice leaving b as standard text

Comment: Your code should work as documented, but it's an obvious bug in CI where the replacement is not properly being done where a replace string matches a substring of another replace string you get your outcome. Please open a bug report here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cryptic pointed, it is a bug in the auto_link method.  ([See source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/url_helper.php#L423))  They are finding all email address in the output and then, they do a replace all (`str_replace`) with the anchored version. So...

```
<p>This is the address a@test.com</p>
<p>This is the second address ba@test.com</p>
```

becomes

```
<p>This is the address <a ...>a@test.com</a></p>
<p>This is the second address b<a ...>a@test.com</a></p>
```

on first pass for the email `a@test.com`.  On the second e-mail, they try to replace `ba@test.com` with the anchored version, but the `str_replace` can not find the address, it has already been replaced.

You could implement your own fix by :

1. Extending the auto_link method of the URL helper. [See documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)
2. Copy the auto_link method from the CodeIgniter source into that new Helper.
3. Replace only the first occurrence of the string. [See this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match).

For example:

```
$str = str_replace($matches['0'][$i], safe_mailto($matches['1'][$i].'@'.$matches['2'][$i].'.'.$matches['3'][$i]).$period, $str);
```

becomes

```
$str = preg_replace('/' . $matches['0'][$i] . '/', safe_mailto($matches['1'][$i].'@'.$matches['2'][$i].'.'.$matches['3'][$i]).$period, $str, 1);
```

That should fix it for you.  I would advise against modifying the system's URL_Helper, you might run into some migration problems later on.

Hope this helps.