# Replacing all occurrences of a string with values from an array

Tags: php, string, loops, phpmyadmin

I am parsing a string before sending it to a DB. I want to go over all `<br>` in that string and replace them with unique numbers that I get from an array followed by a newLine.

For example:

```
str = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>"
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");

my function would return 
"Line 1 \n Line 2 \n Line 3 \n Line 4 \n"
```

Sounds simple enough. I would just do a while loop, get all the occurances of `<br>` using strpos, and replace those with the required numbers+\n using str_replace.

Problem is that I always get an error and I have no idea what I am doing wrong? Probably a dumb mistake, but still annoying.

Here is my code

```
$str     = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>";
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$replaceIndex = 0;

while(strpos($str, '<br>') != false )
{
    $str = str_replace('<br>', $replace[index] . ' ' .'\n', $str); //str_replace, replaces the first occurance of <br> it finds
    index++;
}
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Well first, of all in the first iteration you will replace all the instances of `<br>`.... To do it this way you would have to only replce parts of the string using `substr_replace` which lets you define the postions for he replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a regex and a custom callback, like this:

```
$str = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>";
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$str = preg_replace_callback( '/<br>/', function( $match) use( &$replace) {
    return array_shift( $replace) . ' ' . "\n";
}, $str);
```

Note that this assumes we can modify the `$replace` array. If that's not the case, you can keep a counter:

```
$str = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>";
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$count = 0;
$str = preg_replace_callback( '/<br>/', function( $match) use( $replace, &$count) {
    return $replace[$count++] . ' ' . "\n";
}, $str);
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/IXZcbM) that this outputs:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4
```

Comment: You answer works and str is parsed correctly, but for some reason it is doesn't get inserted into the DB when I call INSERT INTO.

Any ideas why?

Comment: @r3x - How come? Do you have an error message? If you're looking to print the literal `\n` characters instead of letting PHP interpret that to the newline character, change the double quotes around `"\n"` to single quotes.

Comment: Here is my insert query (interestTable is basically the parsed string). `mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(userID,storyID,rank, storyType, interestTable)VALUES('$userID','$storyID','$rank','$storyType','$interestTable')", $dbh1);` If I delete the value of interestTable from this query then everything works fine, but if I add it nothing get sent. As for the error, I did not get any. Weird :S

Comment: I think that the string content is not formatted correctly. Even "Line 1 \nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\n" are not inserted to the DB, so it is not a matter of size.

Comment: Without an error message or more information it's impossible to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Turns out it's a format problem. (There was an `'` in the string.) Your code works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = str_replace('<br>', $replace[$index] . ' ' .'\n', $str);
```

This is replaces **ALL** the occurences of `<br>` it finds.

The correct is to only do one single replacement per iteration: `substr_replace` can replace one single part of a string. Correct would be:

```
while($pos = strpos($str, '<br>') !== false )
{
    $str = substr_replace($str, $replace[$replaceIndex] . ' ' .'\n', $pos, 4); // The <br> is four bytes long, so 4 bytes from $pos on.
    $replaceIndex++;
}
```

(Don't forget the `$` before the `replaceIndex`! `$replaceIndex` is a variable)

Comment: The 4th parameter to `str_replace` is not how many times to replace. It's a reference that's set to how many time it *did* replace.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to count it, you can use this too.

```
$str_expl = explode('<br>',$str);
foreach($str_expl as $index=>&$str)
    if(!empty($str))
        $str .= ($index+1);
$str = implode($str_expl);
```

Comment: if you want to replace the found items with your own array, you can change `str .= ($index+1)` to `str .= $myArray[index];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the `$` in front of variables. Also, try using the [php regex function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match), which allows specifying the number of replacements.

```
<?php
$str     = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>";
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$index = 0;
$count = 1;

while(strpos($str, '<br>') != false )
{
    $str = preg_replace('/<br>/', $replace[$index] . " \n", $str, 1); //str_replace, replaces the first occurance of <br> it finds
    $index++;
}
echo $str
?>
```

Comment: The last parameter does not let you set the number of replacements.  It's a reference that's set to the number of replacements it *did* do.

Comment: I am referring to the $limit variable in [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: I thought you were using the `$count` parameter.  Never mind :-)

Comment: Ah, I see you were responding to the answer directly below mine!

Comment: This requires N regexes to be applied on the string, which can kill performance if the string contains a lot of `<br>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version.  8 formatted lines, no regex, KISS.

```
$str = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>";
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");

$temp = explode("<br>", $str);
$result = "";
foreach ($temp as $k=>$v) {
    $result .= $v;
    if ($k != count($temp) - 1) {
        $result .= $replace[$k];
    }
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback) will help you manipulate the replacement process, and [nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152356/3832970)'s answer shows how it can be done.

However, there can be more matches than the amount of items in the `$replace` array. If you want to re-start using its elements from the 0th item, you need to *reset* the counter once it is equal to the `$replace` array size.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/kdgra):

```php
$text = "Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br> Line <br>";
$replace = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$counter = 0;
$text = preg_replace_callback('~<br\s*/?>~', function($m) use($replace, &$counter) {
    if ($counter === count($replace)) { $counter = 0; }
    return $replace[$counter++];
}, $text);
echo $text;
```

Output: `Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4 Line 1 Line 2`.

Note that the `<br\s*/?>` regex matches `br` tags that can be self-closing (`/?` matches an optional `/` char, and in order to keep `/` unescaped in the pattern, I used the `~` char as a [regex delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)) and that may contain zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`) after `br` and before `/>` / `>`.