# replacing occurences of a word with another on the first line of a text in PHP

Tags: php, replace

let say i have a text :

> this line is the first line of this text called %title%
>
> this line is the second one
>
> the third line, %title% shouldn't be replaced
>
> ...
>
> last line

now I want to use PHP so the text becomes :

> this line is the first line of this text called MY_TITLE
>
> this line is the second one
>
> the third line, %title% shouldn't be replaced
>
> ...
>
> last line

**NOTICE the %title% on the third line also**

what would be the best (fastest) way to do that ?

Comment: @Baba read again the text

Comment: @Oddant i read it perfectly .... str_replace would work

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Comment: @Puciek instead of bragging, propose a decent answer

Comment: @Puciek i can make effort, i can use substr and replace and then put the string together, but as the parenthesis implied, I want to check if a more optimized solution exist, please now help, stop to give lessons.

Comment: @Puciek - You're just being rude. Check out this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments

Comment: @PédeLeão I am aware of that this is a valid question, but I also dare you to read all the comments, original question and so forth.

Comment: use `preg_replace()` as I've suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches:

- If you are sure, that the replacement has to be done exactly one time (i.e. the placeholder will allways be in the first line, and allways only onec), you can use `$result=str_replace('%title%','MY_TITLE',$input,1)`
- If this is not guaranteed, you need to separate the first line:

.

```
$pos=strpos($input,"\n");
if (!$pos) $result=$input;
else $result=str_replace('%title%','MY_TITLE',substr($input,0,$pos)).substr($input,$pos);
```

Comment: I like this solution, do you think the substr's will be harmful for performance if the program involves the use of large files ?

Comment: **Every** such String manipulation in PHP involves copying the string, which is of memory and CPU concern, if the string is big. The solutions I presented are those, that IMHO involve the **least** of it. If you read the string from a file, please update your answer and it might be much easier (think `fopen(); fgets(); str_replace(); fread(); fclose()`)

Comment: actually the last number in str_replace is just a counter set to the number of replacement performed in the string..

Comment: @Oddant: Exactly. So **IF** you are sure, you have the placeholder exactly once in the first line, **THEN** processing the first line is equal to procesing the first occurrence.

Comment: No I mean the last argument is a reference to a variable, once the function is done, the variable contains the number of replacements performed through all the text. it can't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can load only first line to variable, than do `str_ireplace` and then put first line + rest of the file back together.

```
$data = explode("\n", $string);
$data[0] = str_ireplace("%title%", "TITLE", $data[0]);    
$string = implode("\n", $data);
```

Its not the most efficient way imho, but suitable and fast to code.

Comment: thanks for this solution, however if the file is really big, i guess this exploding and imploding will cost a lot of memory + processing usage

Comment: @Whistletoe no it does not, i will explode all the line of the file to return an array in $data

Answer (score 3):

You can use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) it's just one line of code ;)

```
$str = "this line is the first line of this text called %title%\n
this line is the second one\n
the third line, %title% shouldn't be replaced\n
last line";

echo preg_replace('/%title%$/m','MY_TITLE',$str);
```

**Explanation of regex:**

- `/%title%` means `%title%`
- `$` means end of line
- `m` makes the beginning of input (^) and end of input ($) codes also catch beginning and end of line respectively

**Output:**

```
this line is the first line of this text called MY_TITLE
this line is the second one the third line, %title% shouldn't be replaced
last line
```

Comment: i'm sorry i should have noted that %title% can be anywhere in the first line

Comment: You want to remove it just from the first line? So why not to remove only 1 occurence with `$str = str_replace( "%title%", "MY_TITLE", $str, 1 );`