# search a string for a word and replace that word with different links php

Tags: php

Using PHP, how can i replace a word in a string with different links.

I want to replace the word web development with different links in order

> This web development company is great. A good web development starts
>   with...

like so

> This [web development](http://www.google.com/) company is great. A good [web development](http://yahoo.com) starts
>   with...

i have tried using `str_ireplace` but then both links lead to the same site.

Here is my code

```
<?php

$text = 'This web development company is great. A good web development starts with...';


$replaced = str_ireplace(array('web development', 'web development'),array('<a href="http://google.com">web development</a>', '<a href="http://yahoo.com">web development</a>'), $text);

echo $replaced;
```

Comment: How should php be able to know which link to replace "web development" with?  By order?

Comment: Are the links you're wanting to use for replacement always going to appear in the same order? Do you have any control over the original content, ie changing web development to a more usable placeholder?

Comment: The first replacement link in the array should replace the first word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: str\_replace that only acts on the first match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the `preg_replace()` function, as the following:

```
$pattern = '/(web development)(.*)(web development)/';
$replace = '<a href="http://google.com">web development</a>$2<a href="http://yahoo.com">web development</a>';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
echo $result;
```

Hope helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex like:

```
<?php
$text = 'This web development company is great. A good web development starts with...';

$regex = "/[^>]web development[^<]/i";
$replace = array(' <a href="http://google.com">web development</a> ', 
' <a href="http://yahoo.com">web development</a> ');
$count = 1;
$replaced = preg_replace(array($regex,$regex), $replace, $text, $count);

echo $replaced;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match) you can do something like that (with preg_replace) :

```
$str = 'abc and abc'; 
$str = preg_replace('/abc/', 'google', $str, 1); 
$str = preg_replace('/abc/', 'yahoo', $str, 1);
echo $str;
```

It will display : "google and yahoo"

(I hope I understood your need)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with `preg_replace`.

> Searches subject for matches to pattern and replaces them with
>   replacement.

You can set a `limit` to the times the word is going to be replaced.

> **limit:** The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject
>   string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

So, I think you can do a function that first, count the ocurrences of "Web Development" has your text, and then you execute:

```
$text = preg_replace("web development", "<a href='http://www.exemple.com'>web development</a>", $text, 1);
```

x times.

Remember the function preg_replace:

```
preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

See [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in the PHP Manual.