# PHP str_replace different for first instance

Tags: php, str-replace

I've got the following str_replace code:

```
$filterString = "[++] has performed well. [++] is showing good understanding";

echo str_replace("[++]", "Name", $filterString);
```

It basically replaces all instances of `[++]` with Name. However, i would like to only replace the first instance of the `[++]` with Name and all other instances should say He

Any idea how i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to toss in a one-row solution:

```
$filterString = str_replace("[++]","He",preg_replace("/\[\+\+\]/", "Name", $filterString, 1));
```

------EDIT-----

```
$filterString = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?].*?\w/',
                              function($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[0]);},
                              str_replace("[++]","he",preg_replace("/\[\+\+\]/", "Name", $filterString, 1)));
```

This will change all characters that start a sentence to uppercase, plus fix all your earlier issues.

Comment: Thanks, I've just realized that when replacing the ++ from the second instance onwards with the word He, the word He can either be with a capital H or a lower case h depending on if there is a fullstop before it. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I'll get back to you on that...about to eat dinner ;)

Comment: @JohnSmith A new edit was just posted...does this take care of your issues?

Answer (score 2):

[Using str_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

```
echo preg_replace('/\[\+\+\]/', 'Name', $filterString, 1);
```

Comment: But there should be changes "[++]" => "He" as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry.
Then we need 2 steps
$filterString = preg_replace('/\[\+\+\]/', 'Name', $filterString, 1);
$filterString = str_replace("[++]",'He',$filterString);
echo $filterString;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead of `str_replace()`

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

After this first replace, you can use `str_replace()` for all the other ++ to replace with "He".

Later edit:
I checked and I saw that `str_replace()` has a `limit` parameter so you could use it too instead of `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace [++] for "Name" once, you should use preg_replace using the limit parameter, and then you can replace the rest of the string:

```
$filterString = "[++] has performed well. [++] is showing good understanding. [++] is a good student.";
$filterString = preg_replace("/\[\+\+\]/",'Name',$filterString,1);
$filterString = str_replace("[++]",'He',$filterString);     
echo $filterString; //will print "Name has performed well. He is showing good understanding. He is a good student."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$filterString = "[++] has performed well. [++] is showing good understanding.";

$newstr = substr_replace($filterString, "Name", 0, 4);

echo str_replace("[++]", "He", $newstr);
```

Comment: @John Smith: is this help you?