# How to modify a string with a different value when you echoed it with a prefix but not a suffix?

Tags: php, string, replace

There's a code in the software that I'm modifying, which looks `<?php echo $str;>` that have an output of **http://old.example.com/12345-title.html** and when I tried to modify the string with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252710/2007055 technique it didn't work..

And I find out when I do `echo "TEST" . $str;` it returns a different output which looks like **TEST-0/posts/11-cat/22-sub-cat/12345-title.html** but returns *"http://old.example.com/12345-title.htmlTEST"* when I do `echo $str . "TEST";`..

My question is how can I modify that kind of a string?
From *"http://old.example.com/12345-title.html"* into *"http://www.example.com/12345-title.html"* ?

Comment: you can use str_replace() function :-)

Comment: @Bonakid What if that function cannot find the value that's being searched for, because the subject string contains a different value in the other side?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `~http://(.*?)\.~`

```
<?php
$str="http://old.example.com/12345-title.html";
echo $str = preg_replace("~http://(.*?)\.~","http://www.", $str);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
http://www.example.com/12345-title.html
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to store a new string in a new variable, the string that have a different value when you echoed it with a prefix, is already stored in a variable, on the software..

Comment: Nothing happened, the output is still `http://old.example.com/12345-title.html`.. Maybe because the `preg_replace` cannot find the value that's being searched for, because the subject string contains a different value in the other side.

Comment: Nothing happened ? Here's the demo of the same above code. https://eval.in/130065  It works as it should. Maybe should provide a list of inputs on your question.

Comment: Yes I know that your solution and my solution will work on any regular string.. But not to this one, because please considered when I tried to do `echo "TEST" . $str;` it returns a different value which is `TEST-0/posts/11-cat/22-sub-cat/12345-title.html` instead of `TESThttp://old.example.com/12345-title.html`.