# PHP Replace first space with semi-colon

Tags: php

I know that to replace spaces I can use:

```
str_replace(' ', ';', $string);
```

My question is...how do I replace only the first space?

eg: `firstword secondword thirdword` to `firstword;secondword thirdword`

Comment: This might be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/php-str-replace-that-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use preg_replace

```
$subject='firstword secondword thirdword';
$result = preg_replace('%^([^ ]+?)( )(.*)$%', '\1;\3', $subject);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
preg_replace('/ /', ';', $string, 1)
```

Comment: I'm getting:  Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: Edited... sorry it was mistake.

Answer (score 1):

provide replacement count:

```
str_replace(' ', ';', $string,1);
```

refer [wiki](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Getting:  Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: This is actually invalid.

Comment: You're using the 4th parameter wrong. You pass a variable to the 4th parameter and it sets that variable to the number of replacements done. It does not determine how many instances are replaces. For that you want to use preg_replace.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions with preg_replace, or use [stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).
So you would do this:

```
<?php
$original = 'firstword secondword thirdword';
$result = 
  substr($original,0,stripos($original,' '))
  .';'
  .substr($original,stripos($original,' ')+1);

  echo $result;
```

See it running [here](http://ideone.com/9lZaPv).

Comment: Why not `str_replace()`?

Comment: @JackWilliams True ... would be the better option.