# Replacing repeated string in php

Tags: php

I got a string that sometime will have instance of

```
This is Hello World Hello Thanks
```

Notice that Hello was repeat twice, I would like to replace the first "occurence" of Hello and Make it as

```
This is World Hello Thanks
```

Is there a way I can check if there is a word is repeat twice, and to remove the first occurence and get the final string.

The only I could think of is using explode, and get each word by delimiter "white space".

And then I not sure how to proceed on like counting occurance and removing the repeated word.

**Thanks for helping**

Comment: Nice question, any efforts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using str\_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Answer (score 0):

As per this question: [Using str_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

```
$str = 'abcdef abcdef abcdef';
// pattern, replacement, string, limit
echo preg_replace('/abc/', '123', $str, 1); // outputs '123def abcdef abcdef'
```

So you could use:

```
preg_replace('#Hello#', '', $input, 1)
```

To count the amount of times if Hello appears, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

$count = substr_count($input, 'Hello');

Comment: Wrong. `$count` is not for that. `str_replace` will replace all occurrences, you can't specify how many you want removed. `$count`  parameter does this : `If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed. `