# Append text to the first occurrence of an image inside a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to add a string after the first occurrence of an `<img>` tag.

Let say that I have the following html markup:

```
<p>text here text here text here text here text here
<img class="img-class" src="image1.jpg" srcset="" alt="" />
text here text here text here text here text here text here text here
text here text here <img class="img-class" src="image2.jpg" srcset="" alt="" />
text here text here text here text here
```

Using a Regular Expression - How can add text after the first `<img>` tag?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693 :o)

Comment: Nice but I don't want to replace I want to place after the <img> tag some text, the <img> itself should be a regex lookup

Comment: Ah ok - my mistake. You want to do a preg_match then let me create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! this is how I did it:

```
$myText = 'Text I want to add';
preg_match('#(<img[^>]* />)#',$content,$matches);
if ( ! empty( $matches ) AND ! empty( $matches[0] ) )
{
    $content = str_replace($matches[0], $matches[0] . $myText, $content);
}
```

This will add `$myText` right after the first `<img>` match inside `$content`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('#(<img[^>]* />)#','$1.$myText',$content,1)
```

Where $text is the string you want to add the extra and YOURTEXT should be a variable to add after the first image. Remember to add a space to YOURTEXT.

Comment: Such as: `preg_replace('#(<img[^>]* />)#',$1.$myText,$content,1);` ? not sure I got the $1.$Var thing

Comment: Don't worry $1 comes from the preg_replace - its the matching string found in the ( ). Ignore that. But yes your code looks correct.

Comment: Nope, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1.' (T_DNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Comment: Ah sorry - 2 secs and I'll update my answer

Comment: Nope, I got the the right solution, posting it as an answer