# What's special about `str_replace`?

Tags: php

I want to write a function that allows me to replace repetitions of a token in a string with sucessive values from an array, so that `WHERE name = ? and age ?`, `array('joe', 32)` becomes `Where name = joe and age = 32`. (I know variable binding should not be done "manually"; I'm trying to troubleshoot the arguments passed to an eloquent `DB::select` statement).

I wrote this:

```
function str_replace_array($search, array $replace, $subject ) {
    foreach ( $replace as $replacement ) {
        $subject = str_replace($search, $replacement,$subject,1);
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

But php 5.6.20 gives me this error:

```
$ php -l str_replace_array.php
PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in str_replace_array.php on line 5
Errors parsing str_replace_array.php
```

I know it's the function `str_replace()`, because replacing it with a dummy function allows it to pass a syntax check. Although, none have the same variable as both the assignee and and argument-- but is there anything to indicate this wouldn't work in this function?

The [manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) doesn't indicate that any arguments are passed by reference; it indicates a return value and all the examples show assignment.

What is the deal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last parameter of str_replace takes varible to save count, not to make replacement n-times;

use preg_replace

```
function str_replace_array($search, $replace, $subject ) {
    foreach ( $replace as $replacement ) {
        $subject = preg_replace("/\?/", $replacement,$subject, 1);
    }
    return $subject;
}
echo (str_replace_array("?",array(1,2,3),"awdwad ? asdaw ? awdwa? awd"));
```

result: "awdwad 1 asdaw 2 awdwa3 awd"

Comment: with preg_quote fuction you can still pass $search.

Answer (score 4):

Its due to the last parameter of `str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )` that you are setting directly to `1`, you need to set that to some variable say `$count`, as its value will be set to the number of replacements performed. So change to:

```
..
$subject = str_replace($search, $replacement,$subject, $count);
..
```

Comment: Oh sheesh -- is there a way to limit the number of replacements it's doing?

Comment: @user151841 well, you cant do that with just str_replace, you'll have to write some custom function for limiting str_replace

Comment: It looks like `preg_replace()` is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Comment: true, thats the way to go :)