# Using str_ireplace so that it only acts on the first match?

Tags: php

here this topic: [Using str_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match) now I would need this with the **str_ireplace** function

Comment: Could you paste the code you have tried?

Comment: `preg_replace` would be enough. No need of all those *str_replace_first*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting a "i" modifier is enough:

```
function str_ireplace_first($from, $to, $subject)
{
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/i';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject, 1);
}

echo str_ireplace_first('abc', '123', 'abcdef abcdef abcdef');
```

( it's the same answer from @karim79, but adding a final "i" in the `$from` variable ).