# how to find and replace in the first word from the string in php

Tags: php

how to find and replace the first word from the string using php

eg:

```
 $str = 'Super World Hello World';
 replace($str,'Hello','Hi');
```

expected result should be 'Super World Hello World' as it does not match with first word.

eg2:

```
 $str = 'Hello World Hello World';
 replace($str,'Hello','Hi');
```

expected result should be 'Hi World Hello World' as it does match with first word.

please help

Comment: Try str_replace

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-string-exercise-10.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using str\_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my question, my second case it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function for this, passed 3 arguments. Logic is convert string into array by `explode()` function and get first element of the array by using `array_shift()` function and compare with search string

```
function getReplacedStr($str, $searchStr, $replaceWith){
    $arr = explode(' ', $str);
$firstElement = array_shift($arr);
if($searchStr == $firstElement){
    $finalStr =  $replaceWith.' '.implode(' ', $arr);
}else{
    $finalStr = $str;
}
return $finalStr;
}
$replaceWith = 'Hi';
$searchStr = 'Hello';
$str = 'Hello World Hello World';
$str2 = 'Super World Hello World';

echo getReplacedStr($str, $searchStr, $replaceWith);
echo "\n";
echo getReplacedStr($str2, $searchStr, $replaceWith);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/O1kBl)