# PHP find tags in content text and wrap in <a> tags and set limit the number of links

Tags: php

Im finding keywords "denounce,and,demoralized" in a string, and wrapping it in "html a" tags to change it to link with following function...

```
 function link2tags($text, $tags){
        $tags = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($tags));
        $words = explode(',', $tags);

        $linked = array();
        foreach ( $words as $word ){
            $linked[] = '<a href="'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a>';
        }

        return str_replace($words, $linked, $text);
    }

echo link2tags('we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment', 'denounce,and,demoralized');
```

The output of the above function is as follows...

```
Output:

we <a href="denounce">denounce</a> with righteous indignation <a href="and">and</a> dislike men who are so beguiled <a href="and">and</a> <a href="demoralized">demoralized</a> by the charms of pleasure of the moment
```

Here, the word "and" is linked 2 times I want to limit the number of links to a word
Repeat words are only linked once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using str\_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get only first occurrence of words and then need to replace those. Check below code:

```
   function link2tags($text, $tags){
        $tags = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($tags));
        $words = explode(',', $tags);

        $linked = array();
        $existingLinks = array();
        foreach ( $words as $word ){
            if (!in_array($word, $existingLinks)) {
                $existingLinks[] = $word;
                $linked[] = '<a href="'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a>';                
            }
        }

        foreach ($existingLinks as $key => $value) {
            $text = preg_replace("/".$value."/", $linked[$key], $text, 1);
        }
        return $text;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks , but there is an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 7 "$existingLinks = [];"

Comment: what is your PHP version? I have update my answer. check if it works for you.

Comment: I deleted this line " $existingLinks = []" and the code worked

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check existing word as below:

```
if(!in_array($word,$alreadyusedword)) {
      $linked[] = '<a href="'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a>';
      $alreadyusedword[] = $word;
}
```

Comment: your answer autput is:Warning: in_array(): Wrong datatype for second argument on line 8
we <a href="denounce">denounce</a> with righteous indignation <a href="and">and</a> dislike men who are so beguiled <a href="and">and</a> demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment  Again tag "and" 2 tims linked

Comment: Thanks Now I figured out that your code also worked,My php combiler has had a problem