# Make the first sentence in each paragraph an <H3> by referencing two break tags and the next period, question mark, or exclamation mark

Tags: php, replace, strpos, punctuation, html-heading

I'm trying to insert an HTML tag after the first sentence in each paragraph of a given document.

The code I came up with ( I am not a programmer) is working.

The `$insert_pos` is the position where a tag was last inserted. It is needed because there is more than one paragraph in most of the documents.

Now I need to also check for "?" (and possibly "!").

```
$insert_pos = strpos($content, ".", $insert_pos) + 1;
$content= substr_replace( $content, "</tag>", $insert_pos,0 );
```

Some context:

Per CMS, a paragraph is generated with `</br><br />`. So a document will have this format:

```
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </br><br />Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </br><br />voluptua.
```

I need each sentence in between `<br />` and `.` OR `!` OR `?` to become the text inside of a `<h3>` tag. So in the format of `<h3>Lorem ipsum.</h3>`

Comment: strpos can not do that in just one call - so you would need one for every possible character you are looking for. Might make sense to put the characters in an array to begin with, so that you can loop over that. Unclear whether you simply need to do something at every position where any of those characters is found, or only for the first position where any of those characters is found. For the latter, you might want to collect all positions first, and then figure out the minimum.

Comment: Maybe you can use `strpbrk` and then `strpos`

Comment: Maybe the answer given here could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match

Comment: >>you might want to collect all positions first, and then figure out the minimum.<< This was my idea as well, but I was sure there was a more elegant way to accomplish this. So I asked here for advice of people who know php, because what I do right know is only to evaporate from code snippets and documentation on http://php.net @04FS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the replacement to each new paragraph (start of the content or sentence after two break tags, match those occurrences, then use `\K` to "restart the match".  Then match zero or more characters that are not in the punctuation list then a sentence-ending punctuation.  `$0` is the matched substring which is used in the replacement string so that no content is actually lost.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pIeoL))

```
$content = "What in the world? I don't know.<br><br>This is paragraph number 2!  What a fascinating read.<br><br>No matter how many paragraphs, look for one of the three sentence ending punctuations after a fully empty line.  Good stuff!";

$content = preg_replace('~(?:^|<br><br>)\K[^.?!]*[.?!]~', '<h3>$0</h3>', $content);
//                             ^^^^^^^^-- </br><br />  to be more specific
echo $content;
```

Output:

```
<h3>What in the world?</h3> I don't know.<br><br><h3>This is paragraph number 2!</h3>  What a fascinating read.<br><br><h3>No matter how many paragraphs, look for one of the three sentence ending punctuations after a fully empty line.</h3>  Good stuff!
```

Comment: Hey mickmackusa, this is amazing! But it only changes the first sentence of the whole document. So if I want to use preg_replace() one each paragraph I needed to cut the paragraph from the document, then use preg_replace and store it in a new valiable,then repeat and append the following paragraph. Is that right?

Comment: Per CMS a paragraph is generated with '</br><br />'. So a document will have this format _Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </br><br />Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </br><br />voluptua._ I need each Sentence inbetween <br /> and "." OR "!" OR "?"  to be H3. So in the format of <h3> Lorem ipsum</h3>.

Comment: I am not special.  This community is full of knowledgeable people.  Treat everyone with respect and you will have an endless supply of development support.