# Escape a shortcode with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm using `str_replace` to search and replace some shortcodes as `[warning]` with an html code `<span class="warn_class"> Warning</span>`
Here is my code

```
function replace($text) {
    $text = str_replace('[warning]', '<span class="warning_class">Warning </span>', $text); 
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace');
```

As I need to explain to users how to use these shortcodes I'm trying to escape replacing the shortcode  by using a backslashe before it`\[warning]`. Here is my new code

```
function replace($text) {
    $pattern = array();
    $pattern[0]= '[warning]';
    $pattern[1]= '\[warning]';
    $replacement = array();
    $replacement[0] = '<span class="warning_class"> Warning <span>';
    $replacement[1] = '[warning]';
    $text = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace');
```

The problem is that all instances of `[warning]` is being replaced.
Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You could avoid using that replacement for the explanation text, or use HTML entities

Comment: @trincot I got this error message "Only variables can be passed by reference "

Comment: @NicoHaase It is a forum site, so some users may have to explain to others how to use these shrotcodes. So I don't think using HTML entities is a good idea

Comment: Well, that's something you should have mentioned before: you could write a code that can be used as a wrapper around other text which handles the automatic escaping

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. If you need to replace only the first occurrence, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252710/5459839)

Comment: str_replace can also be somewhat surprising: `print str_replace(['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], 'a');` results in `c`.

Comment: @Progrock Not working. It's replacing all text (not only shortcode) by `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) in order to replace all specific shortcodes which **not** have a `\` written before.

Then, `preg_replace()` or `str_replace()` shortcodes preceded with a `\` for removing this one and so showing the original shortcode.

```php
function replace($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/([^\\\\])\[warning\]/', '$1<span class="warning_class"> Warning <span>', $text);
    $text = str_replace('\\[warning]', '[warning]', $text);

    return $text;
}

echo replace('replaced shortcode: _[warning] ; show original shortcode: \\[warning]');
// Output: replaced shortcode: _ Warning ; show original shortcode: [warning]
```

The regex contains four backslashes because how strings are handled in PHP. The real regex pattern should be: `([^\\])\[warning\]` with:

- `(...)` save its content as a reference.
- `[^\\]` find a character which is **not** a `\`.
- `\[warning\]` literally find `[warning]`.

`$1` in second parameter is the reference to `(...)` content (here, it will be the character before the `[` of your shortcode if it's not a backslash).

Comment: Thank you! This did the work, however, it moves any other special character (as _ /) that may come just before the shortcode (not a real problem).

Comment: One more thing, I've seen that replacing `([^\\\\])` by `(?<!\\\\)` and `\ ` by  `\\\\ `is more appropriate.