# How to replace special characters with html tags

Tags: php, html

I am having a challenge, I want to find all strings between 2 special characters and replace the special characters with some html tags. For example,

```
$str = "dog *cat* ping goat *pizza* cow rabbit*";
```

I want a function gets - cat and pizza from the string and then returns

```
$str = "dog <strong>cat</strong> ping goat <strong>pizza</strong> cow rabbit*";
```

Note that `cow rabbit` is ignored because there is no opening * in the string.

What I am trying to do in essence is find special formatting characters between strings according to this WhatsApp doc - https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-format-your-messages/ and replace with their HTML equivalent.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What you are trying to do is make a markdown parser. Why not look into existing implementations of markdown parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to the reply of karim79 with his function [str_replace_first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252705/8010101) that replace only the first matching string, and with [substr_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) function to know how much special character left in the string i made this simple code:

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $content){
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, 1);
}

$str = "dog *cat* ping goat *pizza* cow *rabbit";

$Open_OR_Closed_Tag = false;  // this for to know what tag should put

while (substr_count($str, '*') > 1 || $Open_OR_Closed_Tag) {
    if ($Open_OR_Closed_Tag) {
        $str = str_replace_first("*", "</strong>", $str);
        $Open_OR_Closed_Tag = false;
    } else {
        $str = str_replace_first("*", "<strong>", $str);
        $Open_OR_Closed_Tag = true;
    }
}
echo $str; // dog <strong>cat</strong> ping goat <strong>pizza</strong> cow rabbit*
```