# PHP Bold String Before Specific Char

Tags: php, css, magento2

I have product title with this standard: "Brand name - item title" and I need to transform this string like this:

**Brand name**
item title

So I need 2 things to handle: replace the first dash in the string with "br" and apply bold to the text before the first dash.

I have reached only the first part of the goal with this code:

```
<a class="product-item-link primabold-category" href="<?php echo $_product-> getProductUrl() ?>">
 <?php echo str_replace(' - ', '<br />', $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name')); ?></a>
```

and this CSS:

```
.primabold-category::first-line { font-weight: 900; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px;}
```

But the result is not as expected because it "bold" only the first line, even if the text before the dash is on two lines..

Here a real title example:

POLO RALPH LAUREN - Camicia donna in Oxford azzurro

expected result:

**POLO RALPH LAUREN**
Camicia donna in Oxford azzurro

As you can see from the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngGPJ.png), when I'm on mobile view, "lauren" is on the second line and it's not bold :(

--> I have found a javascript that suits the expected result:

```
<a class="ProductList-title primabold-category" style="font-weight: 100;">Polo ralph lauren - T-shirt oudspeaker</a> <script> function changeBrandName() { var prodList = document.querySelectorAll("a.primabold-category"); for (var i = 0; i < prodList.length; i++) { var text = prodList[i].innerText; var index = text.indexOf('-'); var lower = text.substring(0, index); var higher = text.substring(index + 1); prodList[i].innerHTML = lower.bold() + '<br />' + higher; } } changeBrandName(); </script>
```

BUT javascript is not fired anytime the layered navigation load new lines of products, so I think that using PHP would be the perfect solution, if possibile.

Comment: So output a `<strong>` tag before the title, and replace `-` inside of it with `</strong><br />` …? (And remove the CSS again, `::first-line` won’t work properly for your purposes, if you can not force the first part to be on one single line in the first place.)

Comment: @04FS as long as there is no `-` in the rest of the text.

Comment: @NigelRen yes, good point. If this needs to be restricted to replacing only the first occurence of `-`, which `str_replace` can’t do natively, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/ has approaches to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code instead:

```
$brand= $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name');

$explodedBrand=explode(' - ',$brand,2);

if(count($explodedBrand) > 1){
    $brand = '<span class="bold">'.$explodedBrand[0].'</span>'.'<br>'.$explodedBrand[1];
}

echo $brand;
```

remember to define `bold` class in your CSS file.