# Link all tags within content variable

Tags: php, laravel

I want to link all tags inside content variable, I can achieve it with foreach, but if one tag is `car wash` and another is `car` it's creating link inside link, how to avoid that ?

My code:

```
$tags = Tag::all();

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if(stripos($content, $tag->name) !== false) {
        $content = str_ireplace($tag->name, '<a href="' . route('tag.show', [$tag->id, slug($tag->name)]) . '" target="_blank">' . $tag->name . '</a>', $content);
    }
}
```

One of the solutions would be sorting tags by length, from small to larg, but nah, I need a better solution

EDIT: Storing already matched tags in a new array and checking with foreach and strpos if they contain substring before replacing, will be a solution for that, but another issue, strpost ans str_replace will match partial words like, if tag is car and content contains caring, there will be a partial match and it will also get replaced, how to avoid partial match ?

EDIT 2: Thanks @Kinglish for help, final code:

```
$tags = Tag::orderByRaw('CHAR_LENGTH(name) DESC')->get();

$linkedTags = [];
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    foreach ($linkedTags as $linkedTag) {
        if(stripos($linkedTag, $tag->name) !== false) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }

    if(stripos($content, $tag->name) !== false) {

        $pos = stripos($content, $tag->name);
        $disallowedCharacters = [
            '-',
            '/',
            '@',
            '\\',
            '#',
            '*',
            '&'
        ];

        if ($pos != 0) {
            $charBefore = substr($content, $pos -1, 1);
            if (ctype_alpha($charBefore) || ctype_digit($charBefore) || in_array($charBefore, $disallowedCharacters)) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        $charAfter = substr($content, $pos + strlen($tag->name), 1);
        if (ctype_alpha($charAfter) || ctype_digit($charAfter) || in_array($charAfter, $disallowedCharacters)) {
            continue;
        }

        $linkedTags[] = $tag->name;
        $content = str_ireplace($tag->name, '<a href="' . route('tag.show', [$tag->id, slug($tag->name)]) . '" target="_blank">' . $tag->name . '</a>', $content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using str\_replace so that it only acts on the first match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252693/using-str-replace-so-that-it-only-acts-on-the-first-match)

Comment: sorting from small to large seems like an elegant enough method. Why not that?

Comment: @Kinglish Check my updated question, I am from large to small because large tags will be more relevant to content

Comment: @Nevermind23 append and prepend `\b` in pregmatch with your tag name at the time of replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's an idea that might work for you...

Store the found tags in an array and remove from content so they don't get picked up twice. Then reassemble the content at the end...

```
    // sort array from longest to shortest 
function sort($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}

usort($tags,'sort');



$found=array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if(stripos($content, $tag->name) !== false) {
        // test the string for partial match
        $pos = stripos($content, $tag->name);
        // test the character before
        if ($pos != 0) {
            $charBefore = substr($content, $pos -1, 1);
            if (ctype_alpha($charBefore)) {
               // its a partial, the character before the string is a letter
               continue;
            }
        }
        // test the character after
        $charAfter = substr($content, $pos + strlen($tag->name), 1);
            if (ctype_alpha($charAfter)) {
               // its a partial, the character after the string is a letter
               continue;
            }


        $storedlink = '<a href="' . route('tag.show', [$tag->id, slug($tag->name)]) . '" target="_blank">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
        $found[] = $storedlink;
        // get ref
        $ref = '[!'.count($found).'!]';
        $content = str_ireplace($tag->name, $ref, $content);
    }

    // reassemble
    $ctr=0;
    foreach ($found as $tag) {
        $content = str_replace('[!'.$ctr.'!]', $tag, $content) ;
        $ctr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, you made it with a little bit harder way but that will work, have you read 2nd part? avoiding partial match

Comment: I made it even uglier, but I think this would work. You test the character before and after the possible tag to see if it's a letter (rather than a space or punctuation). If it is, then it fails the test

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it a little bit, not tested yet, but I think it will work

Comment: @Kinglish How did you test this? I got `usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given` error on laravel 8.

Comment: I assumed $tags was an array.

Comment: $tags = $tags->toArray()

Comment: @Kinglish we made a mistake ... If content contains both `car` and `caring` then it will replace both, I have changed code to replace first match only

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to make link tags, avoiding partial match:

```
$tags = Tag::all();
$space_order_tags = [];
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $space_order_tags[count(explode(' ', $tag->name))][] = $tag;
}

$replaced = [];
foreach (array_reverse($space_order_tags) as $tag_array) {
    foreach ($tag_array as $tag) {
        $replaced[$tag->name] = [$tag->id, hash('md5', $tag->name)];
        $content = preg_replace( "/\b$tag->name\b/", $replaced[$tag->name][1], $content);
    }
}

foreach (array_keys($replaced) as $tag_name) {
    $content = str_ireplace($replaced[$tag_name][1], '<a href="' . route('tag.show', [$replaced[$tag_name][0], slug($tag_name)]) . '" target="_blank">' . $tag_name . '</a>', $content);
}

var_dump($content);
```